# Mechanism for yielding cpu

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a module which creates a kthread. I want this kthread to record some statistics, then yield the cpu. It will record statistics when it runs again. What is the correct way to do this? Is

```
set_tsk_need_reched(task); 
schedule();
```

the right way to do this? (It seems not to do what I expect)

Answer (score 1):

If I correly remember Linux kernel have a yield() function that can be used to voluntarily pass processor control to some another thread in the system (kernel will decide itself what thread will be running next). Some notes:

- You need to call yield() from the context of your thread.
- You needn't to invoke scheduler explicitly after that. yield() code will force rescheduling by itself.

Comment: Commenting on an old thread, but hopefully it will save someone from making this mistake:  If you read the comment in core.c, it says: "* Do not ever use this function, there's a 99% chance you're doing it wrong."   You should use cond_resched() instead...